# Replace an attribute name in an Xml column with a SQL query

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I need to replace the attribute's name "TimeStamp" by "Timestamp" in the following XML example :

```
<CMD CommandID="6000">
   <DATA>
      <ReportData Key="10000">
         <Event TimeStamp="2013-03-07 15:42:49.000" Name="ABC" />
         <Event TimeStamp="2013-03-07 15:42:50.000" Name="DEF" />
         <Event TimeStamp="2013-03-07 16:22:03.000" Name="GHI" />
      <ReportData>
   <DATA>
<CMD>
```

It is stored in a SQL Server 2008 database within a column of `XML` type.

I tried something like this but it's incorrect:

```
DECLARE @variable NVARCHAR(20) = 'Timestamp'

UPDATE MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
SET MyXmlColumn.modify('replace value of (/CMD/DATA/ReportData/Event/@TimeStamp) with sql:variable("@variable") ')
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't do that; you can update the **values** of elements and attributes, but you cannot change the attribute name in a XML

Answer (score 5):

You can use [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx).

```
update MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable
set MyXMLColumn = replace(cast(MyXMLColumn as nvarchar(max)), '<Event TimeStamp="', '<Event Timestamp="')
```

Comment: How hasn't this had a +1 over 3 years!? Nice solution